# abrir un archivo en Python, preguntando antes el nombre

Tags: python

Estimados, tengo un problema, resulta que tengo un código y quiero que el usuario me de el nombre del archivo (incluido el .txt) y que con esto pueda abrir el archivo, el punto es que para abrirlo se necesita las comillas, pero como este nombre lo guardo dentro de una variable, si al nombre de la variable le pongo comillas lo paso convierte en un string. Les dejo el código, muchas gracias

```
nombre=input("ingrese nombre del archivo (con el .txt por favor): ")
archivo=open(nombre)
lineas=arch.readlines()
print(lineas)
for linea in lineas:
    numer=linea.split()
    print(numer)
    qw.append(numer)
for i in range(0,len(qw)):
    if qw[i][0]=="G":
        posicion_gallina(int(qw[i][1]),int(qw[i][2]),int(qw[i][3]),int(qw[i][4]))
        jug=2
    else:
        posicion_coyote(int(qw[i][1]),int(qw[i][2]),int(qw[i][3]),int(qw[i][4]))
        jug=1
arch.close()
```

Comment: Vicente, el único problema que veo es que falta el modo en la apertura (escritura, lectura, etc). no veo el problema de hacer `archivo = open(nombre, "r")` por ejemplo para leer.

Comment: estimado, yo solamente puse, después de eso lineas=archivo.readlines(), ademas de eso, entonces hay que poner el "r"???

Comment: definitivamente, me faltaba eso, pero ahora tengo otro problema, resulta que con este código.                                                            
       arch=open(nombre,"r")
       lineas=arch.readlines()
       print(lineas)
 cuando uso el print, no me devuelve nada, y se que el archivo que quiero abrir tiene texto

Comment: Corrijo mi comentario inicial, si vas a leer, no debiera haber problema puedes obviar el modo por que por defecto es `r`, igual sigo sin ver el problema, el código que acabas de comentar es válido y funciona. Que es lo que estarías esperando que haga el programa?

Comment: que el print me devolviera lo que tengo en el archivo para poder utilizarlo; pondré mi código en el comentario más arriba

Comment: Si no tienes una excepción `FileNotFoundError` podemos descartar que el archivo no exista. Si tampoco  tienes una excepción `UnicodeDecodeError` también podemos descartar el problema de leer un archivo binario como texto. Revisa que el archivo de texto tenga contenido, recuerda que `readlines()` debiera devolverte una lista con todas las líneas incluido el fin de línea `\n`

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado Patricio, pero ya revise mi archivo y se que tiene texto, agradezco la ayuda... Ya no se que más hacerle

Comment: tienes puesto `arch.readlines` pero la variable no es `archivo`?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

he cambiado el nombre de la variable arch, por archivo y ha leido perfectamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]